# VSCode how to set "when" in keyboard shortcuts tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

More specifiaclly I need VSCode to "run python file in terminal" on Ctrl+R if .py file is opened, or perform a build task otherwise. There is a "when" field in keyboard shortcuts menu but I can't figure out how to set it properly for my case.

Comment: try `"when": "editorLangId == 'python'"`

Comment: Thank you! In a gui tab it's `editorLangId == 'python'`. Please write this as an answer and I'll upvote and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the languageId in the `keybindings.json` file `when` clause.

```
"when": "editorLangId == 'python'"
```

and in the GUI use `editorLangId == 'python'`